# How is the data labelled in order to train a region proposal network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, r-cnn

I don't get how the training of the RPN works. From the forward propagation, I have $W \times H \times k$ outputs from the RPN.

How is the training data labeled such that I can use the loss function and update the weights through bach propagation?  Is the training data labeled in the same shape of the output, as there are $W \times H \times k$ anchor boxes and we use the loss function directly or what?

Comment: Did u find any answer?I am interested too